# Laravel - PHP Artisan Serve - Keeps serving from previous location

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-artisan

My problem is as followed:

I created a laravel project, worked on it excessively and used the build in server by using the following command.

```
php artisan serve
```

After some time realised this might not be the best location for my laravel project to be on my computers harddisk, so I copied the entire folder to a new location.

Now when I use the same command,

```
php artisan serve
```

,when having navigated to the new location of the project with the terminal, it still tries to serve the project from the hard-disk location that it used to be located at.

Is this a cache problem, or is it more like some hidden laravel config file?

Help will be more than appreciated.

Laravel Version:  5.1

Comment: How do you know it is still trying to serve from previous location? What error does it produce?

Comment: I got another copy of the project still on the previous location. When I change in the controllers at the right location and die and dump something it works. When I change something in the view at the right location, nothing changes.   
When, instead of changing something in the view at the right location, I change something in the view at the folder of the previous location, the change is visible in my browser while serving the laravel project at the new location.
Also, when I delete the project at the previous location and serve the new one, it showed nothing at all.

Comment: This is very strange to me. Just a thought, check your `PATH` (if you are in windows) variable and check if any laravel or composer-related path is actually pointing to the previous location. Also, just as a desperate measure, maybe do a `composer dump-autoload` after navigating to the new location in your terminal. Maybe the issue is somehow with composer or composer.json. Maybe.

Comment: Everything seemed to be in order, and even composer dump-autoload had no effect on the issue. I ended up putting the project back to it's previous location and working further like that.

Comment: Maybe you've hardcoded a link to the previous location..

Comment: I use the url() tag everywhere in my views, and have never hardcoded (or even adjusted) any folder structure or links in the actual framework config or such, so I really doubt that to be the case. 
Is there in any config file perhaps with a reference referring hardcoded to the creation folder / initiation folder of laravel perhaps? If so,it could potentially explain the problems I was facing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar problem. I updated the homestead.yaml file for the correct location and then run reprovision. This solved my problem